# Flutter - Draggable AND Scaling Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

So for this application (Windows, Web) I have 2 requirements:

1. User can drag around widgets on the screen (drag and drop) to any location.
2. The app must scale to screen/window size

For (1) I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187854/3367856).
For (2) I used [this solution](https://stasheq.medium.com/scale-whole-app-or-widget-contents-to-a-screen-size-in-flutter-e3be161b5ab4).

As mentioned in the code comment below I can't have both:

If I set `logicWidth` and `logicHeight` dynamically depending on the window size, the dragging works fine but the draggable widgets won't scale but instead stay the same size regardless of the window size.

If I set `logicWidth` and `logicHeight` to a constant value (the value of the current `cleanHeight` ) the dragging will be messed up for other screen sizes but then the draggable widgets will scale  correctly with the window size.

In other words: for the dragging to work nicely these values need to be matching the window size at any time. But by changing these values I ruin the scaling I need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

//containing widgets to drag around
const List<Widget> draggableWidgets = [
  DraggableWidget(
      draggableWidget: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    radius: 32,
  )),
  DraggableWidget(
      draggableWidget: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    radius: 24,
  )),
];

class FrontPageWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const FrontPageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/frontPage';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //screen height and padding
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final padding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding;
    // Height (without status and toolbar)
    final cleanHeight = height - padding.top - kToolbarHeight;

    //either make those values dynamic (cleanHeight updates depending on screen size / window size) OR constant (961px is the cleanHeight on full screen)
    //if values are dynamic => the draggable widgets not scaling to screen size BUT dragging works fine
    //if values are constant => the draggable widgets do scale to screen size BUT dragging is messed
    final logicWidth = cleanHeight; //961
    final logicHeight = cleanHeight; //961

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main Page'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
          child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: logicWidth,
                height: logicHeight,
                child: Stack(
                  children: draggableWidgets,
                ),
              ))),
    );
  }
}

class DraggableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget draggableWidget;
  const DraggableWidget({Key? key, required this.draggableWidget})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
    return Center(
      child: MatrixGestureDetector(
        onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
          notifier.value = m;
        },
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: notifier,
          builder: (ctx, child) {
            return Transform(
              transform: notifier.value,
              child: Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [draggableWidget],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is wrapping the `draggableWidget` in a `Transform` widget and set the `scale` factor in relation to the dimensions:

```
   child: AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: notifier,
      builder: (ctx, child) {
        final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        return Transform(
          transform: notifier.value,
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Transform.scale(
                    scale: height / 1000,
                    child: draggableWidget)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, instead of getting the height from the MediaQuery get it from the LayoutBuilder, I noticed it is working much better when resizing the window.

```
body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
        return SizedBox.expand(
            child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    child: Stack(
                        children: draggableWidgets,
                    ),
                )
            )
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: This approach leads to the same behaviour. The `CircleAvatar` won't resize anymore when the window resizes

Answer (score 0):

**Another way of achieving this:**
To drag around widgets on the screen (drag and drop) to any location.

- [Draggable Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_widget)
- Check Flutter [Draggable class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html)

And to scale screen/window size.

- [Relative Scale](https://pub.dev/packages/relative_scale)
- [FlutterScreenUtil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)